# How to Select first index of first combobox and disable other comboboxes and reset the values of other combobox with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have three combobxes. All comboboxes have values : "Select","one","two""three"

Here is the screnario :

If "Select" is selected from First Combobox, then it should disable all the comboboxes and reset the values to their first index.

### jQuery

```
$("select").change(function(e){

    if($("#box_g1 option:selected").prop("selectedIndex",0)){
        $("#box_g2").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#box_g3").attr("disabled", true);
        // and so on
        $("#box_g5").attr("disabled", true); 
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<select name="n1" id="box_g1">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select name="n2" id="box_g2">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select name="n3" id="box_g3">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Here `box_g1` is first combobox. And disabling other comboboxes from 2 to 5.

Comment: sure. Edit the question to add HTML. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").change(function(e){

    if($("#box_g1").val() == "Select"){
        $("#box_g2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#box_g3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // and so on
        $("#box_g5").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    }
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mkma3803/11/)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Sharing you the fiddle, with the code you have given. Please have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/mkma3803/6/ . Also by default, both the comboboxes should be disabled by default.

Comment: I think i got the point and i have updated the answer too ... Please check the fiddle [link]:(http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/mkma3803/18/) My Fiddle

Comment: @k00989  Good for you!!